# Coding lines appear after each closed div. (only in DOM inspector)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I had some very strange annoying results while working on my 'project'.
To loop through MySQL results I used a while loop. 
One of the lines echo'ed in the while loop now keeps appearing after every closed div.
This is only visible in firebug or another DOM inspector and not in the source code.
I have no idea what is causing it, so any help is appreciated.
Underneath I included all the code involved.

Thanks,

Sam

Btw. This is still in early development so please take that into consideration.

Code:

Firebug:

```
<div class="contentainer_wrapper">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="sidebar_navigation gradient">
<ul class="navigation">
<li id="nav1" class="active tip-right" style="height: auto;" data-original-title="Dashboard">
<li id="nav2" class="tip-right" style="height: auto;" data-original-title="Forms">
<li id="nav3" class="tip-right" style="height: auto;" data-original-title="UI Elements">
<li id="nav4" class="tip-right" style="height: auto;" data-original-title="Typography">
<li id="nav5" class="tip-right" style="height: auto;" data-original-title="Tables">
<li id="nav6" class="tip-right" style="height: auto;" data-original-title="Gallery">
<li id="nav7" class="tip-right" style="height: auto;" data-original-title="Grid">
<li id="nav8" class="tip-right" style="height: auto;" data-original-title="Charts">
<a class="i_charts" onclick="load_page('nav8', 'test.html')"> </a>
</ul>
<a class="i_charts" onclick="load_page('nav8', 'test.html')"> </a>
</div>
<a class="i_charts" onclick="load_page('nav8', 'test.html')"> </a>
</div>
<a class="i_charts" onclick="load_page('nav8', 'test.html')">
<div id="canvas" class="content_wrapper">This page was loaded succesfully :D</div>
<div id="loading_modal" class="modal hide fade">
</a>
</div>
<a class="i_charts" onclick="load_page('nav8', 'test.html')"> </a>
</div>
<a class="i_charts" onclick="load_page('nav8', 'test.html')"> </a>
</div>
<a class="i_charts" onclick="load_page('nav8', 'test.html')"> </a>
</div>
<a class="i_charts" onclick="load_page('nav8', 'test.html')">
</body>
</html>
```

Php File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta name="author" content="Sam Kool">
<title>Admin panel</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-responsive.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"/>
<!--[if IE 8]><link href="css/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet"><![endif]--><!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>

<body onLoad="prepare()">
<?php  
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    header('Location: http://localhost/CMS/Admin/');
}   
include ('../config.php');

?>
<div class="highligts_content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="stats">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="statistics">
            <ul class="quickstats">
            <?php  
            $conn = mysql_connect($config['db_host'], $config['db_user'], $config['db_pass']);
            $conn = mysql_select_db($config['db_db']);
            $mysql['sql'] = " SELECT *
                        FROM admin_layout
                        WHERE enabled = '1' and type = 'quickstats'
                        ";
            $mysql['query'] = mysql_query($mysql['sql']);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql['query'])){
                echo '<li> <a href="#"> <img src="../img/icons/'.$row["image"].'" alt=""> <span>'.$row["title"].'</span> </a> </li>';
            }
            mysql_close();
            ?>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contentainer_wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span12">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="sidebar_navigation gradient">
            <ul class="navigation">
              <?php
              $i = 1;
              $conn = mysql_connect($config['db_host'], $config['db_user'], $config['db_pass']);
              $conn = mysql_select_db($config['db_db']);
              $mysql['sql'] = " SELECT *
                          FROM admin_components
                          WHERE enabled = '1'
                          ";
              $mysql['query'] = mysql_query($mysql['sql']);
              while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql['query'])){
                  echo '<li id="nav'.$i.'" class="tip-right" data-original-title="'.$row["title"].'" style="height: auto;">';
                  echo '<a class="'.$row["icon"].'" onClick="load_page(\'nav'.$i.'\', \''.$row["url"].'\')">'; 
                  echo '<span class="tab_label" style="visibility: visible;">'.$row["title"].'</span>';
                  echo '<span class="tab_info" style="visibility: visible;">'.$row["description"].'</span></li>'; 
                  $i ++;

              }
              mysql_close();
              ?>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content_wrapper" id="canvas"> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal hide fade" id="loading_modal">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3>Loading....</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script> 
function load_page(id, component){
    if($('#'+id).attr('class') == 'active tip-right'){
        alert('nope');
        return; 
    }
    $('.navigation li').each(function(i){
        var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
        if(myClass == 'active tip-right'){
            $(this).attr('class', 'tip-right');
        }
        });
        $('#'+id).attr('class', 'active tip-right');
        $('#loading_modal').modal('show');
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('#canvas').load('/SCMS/admin/components/'+component, function(){
            $('#loading_modal').modal('hide');
        });
        },1000);
}
function prepare(){
    $('#nav1').attr('class', 'active tip-right');
    $('#canvas').load('/SCMS/admin/components/dashboard.php');
    $('#loading_screen').modal({
    keyboard: false,
    hide: true
    })  
}
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Often indicates a tag is not closed, or they are closed in the wrong order. What is the line that keeps appearing?

Comment: Take a screenshot of your site

Comment: Close your `a` tag in the list element.

Comment: Forexample, in your second while loop, it appears you open an `a` tag and dont close it.

Comment: <a class="i_charts" onclick="load_page('nav8', 'test.html')"> </a> keeps repearing.

Comment: You're not telling it to print the closing `a` tag anywhere and DOM inspector is likely trying to fix the incorrect code for you.

Comment: @Ally he's responding to my initial question

Comment: might as well close the <meta> tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM inspector is almost always correct, your HTML source is wrong. When things like this happen, it usually indicates you forgot to close a tag, or that you closed them in the wrong order.

This is an extremely easy mistake to make when echoing out html, because you dont usually have indentation or IDE color coding to help you out.

In your second while loop, it appears you opened an `a` tag and didnt echo out the closing tag.

```
echo '<li id="nav'.$i.'" class="tip-right" data-original-title="'.$row["title"].'" style="height: auto;">';
//OPENED AN A TAG HERE
echo '<a class="'.$row["icon"].'" onClick="load_page(\'nav'.$i.'\', \''.$row["url"].'\')">'; 
echo '<span class="tab_label" style="visibility: visible;">'.$row["title"].'</span>';
echo '<span class="tab_info" style="visibility: visible;">'.$row["description"].'</span></li>'; 
//OOPS, ENDED LI WITHOUT ENDING A
```

Comment: Oh god, sooo embarrasing :'(.

Thought I went over that, guess not.
 
Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Dont be, we've all done it. If you move to a templating engine like Twig or Smarty, or otherwise try to avoid echoing html, its a lot easier to avoid because the IDE can interpret your HTML and warn you of unclosed tags.